# JApplet dimensions in another class

Tags: java, swing, size, japplet

I have a normal JApplet class named `game.java` and I have another class named `room.java`.
`room.java` has a `draw()` method but it requires the use of `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` from the `game.java` so that it can resize itself on each `paint()` if the user resizes the window. I know I could create method and just pass it to `room.java` but I was wondering if there was another way for `room.java` to access the JApplets height and width.

Comment: The actual width/height of a room is not controlled by the applet so much as an architect.  The applet in turn, can inspect the sizes of the objects it is rendering, then appropriate to its current view and zoom level, set a translate and scale the `Graphics2D` that it passes to the various objects to be drawn.